# How to change field name in Review tab(Product page tab) as Nickname to Firstname

Tags: magento-2.1

In product Page tab - Review tab I want to change name of one field: Nickname
to Firstname.
I have attached image here describing the same.
Please advise me on that.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change name based on i18n translation file.

Just create i18n folder at design or module level,
Create en_US.csv  file

For design level,

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv
```

For Module level,

```
app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Put name in csv as below,

```
Nickname,Firstname
```

Run below command from root,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```